# How to have one mandatory and two optional positional arguments?

Tags: python, django, oop, args

I need to run a python file as follows

python runnning_program.py argument1 [argument2] [argument3]

```
def main(argument1,argument2 = default2, argument3 = default2):
   code


if __name__ == '__main__': 
   ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ap.add_argument("argument1")
   kwargs = vars(ap.parse_args())
   main(**kwargs)
```

How to add argument2 and argument3 as optional positional arguments?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully: "optional positional" arguments is a contradiction.  If you call `main(arg1, opt)`, how does the interpreter know which of the two optional parameters gets the argument `opt`?  If you intend that they fill in order, then you're merely overloading the signature, or avoiding using a parameter list.

Comment: In short, you *can* do this with slightly different syntax.  Research more.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this does not work.

To elaborate a little:
Positional arguments are mandatory. The quick take-away is, that a function in Python can always (and **will** always) be treated as having the following signature:

`def some_function(*args, **kwargs):`

This implies that positional arguments are basically just a list of arguments to the interpreter and will be expanded when passed to the function.
Therefore, all positional arguments need to be present when calling the function.

That is a huge difference to how named arguments are passed ("keyword arguments"):
They are a dictionary of the kind

`{'parameter_name': 'parameter_value'}`

They are always present as they get defined by having a default value.

To get back to your original issue:
When calling your function, the option to pass kwargs by position instead of by name may help you.

so, instead of

`main(argument1, argument2 = 'default2', argument3 = 'default3')`

you can always call

`main(argument1, 'default2', 'default3')` instead.

Also, you may want to have a look at the `argparse` library.